# at-loader Checking finished with xx errors on SystemJS to Webpack migration

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack

i fork this project:

https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack.git

My project is on SystemJS and i want to migrate it to webpack. So i copied my components to the new structure, i copy my dependencies from my old project.

First i execute npm install and everything was fine when download the dep. Later, i do npm start and i recive this error:

```
$ npm start

> app@0.0.0 start C:\Node.js\project-oak\angular-webpack
> npm run server


> app@0.0.0 server C:\Node.js\project-oak\angular-webpack
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080

 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from http://localhost:8080/
Content not from webpack is served from ./src/public
404s will fallback to /index.html
 10% building modules 6/10 modules 4 active ...gular-webpack\node_modules\url\url.js
[at-loader] Using typescript@2.2.2 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from C:\Node.js\project-oak\angular-webpack/tsconfig.json.

 94% asset optimization
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Checking finished with 94 errors
```

After the last line doest'n show anything.

Can you help me?

Here is my files:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules doc dist && npm cache clean",
    "clean-install": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "clean-start": "npm run clean-install && npm start",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --progress --profile",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "lint": "tslint --force \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "e2e-live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "karma start",
    "posttest": "remap-istanbul -i coverage/json/coverage-final.json -o coverage/html -t html",
    "test-watch": "karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch",
    "ci": "npm run e2e && npm run test",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json src/app/app.component.ts",
    "start": "npm run server",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server -- --hot",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver-update"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.2",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.35",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.12.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "angular2-chartist": "~0.10.1",
    "angular2-google-maps": "~0.16.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "chartist": "~0.9.8",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "jquery": "~3.1.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "~1.1.16",
    "ng2-toasty": "^2.5.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "~0.19.41",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.17",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "yargs": "^4.7.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.39",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not @ceebreenk